# NSImageView rending a blurry NSimage despite it being of the same size

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have an `NSCollectionViewItem` with an `NSImageView` (32x32) to which i supply a @1x image of the same size.

It looks perfect in the interface builder, but when the app is built, the resolution looks quite off. Is there any particular reason for this?

[image]

Just to add that the Image in the asset manager also has a @2x

[image]

EDIT: Still investigating this issue, but I have just noticed that If the collection view which contains the collection item, which contains the `NSImageView` is enclosed by a **bordered** `NSSCrollView` the images are perfect (.ie non blurry)

Comment: Probably the position ends up at a fractional pixel somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you draw images in frames with either the x,y coords or the height and width having fractions you end up with blurry images. passing the drawingRect through [NSIntegralRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1391136-nsintegralrect?language=objc) fixes that.